# Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub:

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty

I am trying to deploy my app using the Jetty plug in with IntelliJ. I am getting this error message. I am able to deploy the app using Tomcat successfully.

Can anyone suggest why?

```
Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason:
    java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub:
    javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException:
    error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]
```

Answer (score 2):

We've experienced same problem but with Tomcat. Problem was in the configuration of application server: "Tomcat Home" and "Tomcat base directory" had a backslash at the end.

Correct path: `C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat`
Failing path: `C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat\`

Comment: That doesn´t work for me. I use IntelliJ 2018.2 and the configuration is ok.
In the end, I fixed it by using Tomcat 8.5 instead of 8.0. Any ideas why this works?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with **Tomcat** and **IntelliJ**, and as @eire user pointed out, there was a problem in the path of a Tomcat directory.

So I had to go into **Edit Configurations** for my **Tomcat Server** in **IntelliJ**, then on the **Run/Debug Configurations** window, I went on the **Startup/Connection** pane, and for both *Run* and *Debug* configs, I had to change the path for the CATALINA_BASE environnement variable.

Basically it pointed to *C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0* instead of pointing to 
*C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0*, so I changed that, and had no issue afterwards.

You can check these screenshots for more clarity.

[1 - Edit Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYHT6.png)

[2 - Startup/Connection Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJO93.png)